# プロトコルから要求される演算子関数

Tags: swift, swift3

```
protocol BaseProtcol{
    static func ＜(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
    static func MethodA()-> Bool
}

struct AClass : BaseProtcol{
    static func MethodA()->Bool{
        return true
    }
}

func ＜(lhs: AClass, rhs: AClass) -> Bool{
    return true
}



let a = AClass()
let b = AClass()

print( a
```

BaseProtocolには、二つのstatic関数が宣言されており、
このプロトコルを適合する場合、２つの関数を実装します。

このとき、構造体のメンバとして実装すべきだと思いますが、
＜演算子関数は、メンバ関数としてまたはグローバル関数としてとどちらでも定義できます。
下記のMethodA()はメンバ関数としてしか実装できません。

この違いは、演算子とそうでないものに見えますが、なぜ演算子はそのようなことが
許されるのでしょうか。教えてください。

疑問なのは、演算子をグローバル関数として実装したとき、
AClassがBaseProtcolに適合しているといえるのかというところです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3.0.1) - Advanced Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-ID28)
このApple文書を調べてみました。この中の「Operator Methods」の項で、プロトコルでなく、構造体における演算子の定義（新規定義と、オーバーロード含めて）について、旧版（Swift 2.2）と比べてみました。

*Swift 3.0.1 Edition*

> The operator method is defined as a type method on Vector2D, with a method name that matches the operator to be overloaded (+).

（「Vector2D」は、サンプルコード中の構造体名）

*Swift 2.2 Edition*

> The operator function is defined as a global function with a function name that matches the operator to be overload (+).

大きな変更になっていることがわかります。「グローバル関数」で定義するのは、Swift 2.2のやり方。タイプメソッドで定義するのは、Swift 3.0.1のやり方です。
Xcode 8では、Swift 2の記法が完全に廃止されたものもあれば、このようにSwift 2の記法でも書けるものもあるようです。
やはり、タイプメソッドで、演算子の定義はするべきではないかと思います。

Comment: swift3.01の書き方がタイプメソッドを推奨しているならば、apple提供のリファレンスで、例えばInt型にそのメソッドの記載されているべきだと思うのですが。。。
String型は、「Operator Functions」という項目で、演算子関数の説明があります。リファレンスから見た時、Int型の演算子は、どうやって参照するのでしょうか。

Comment: AppleのSwift 3に関するリファレンスは、まだ完成していない、未完成であるというのが、私の認識です。おっしゃっているのと似たことで、私は最近まで（昨日まで）「`Array`を`==`で比較できない。`Array`のリファレンスに記述がないから」と思い込んでいました。ところが、コードを書いてみると比較できるんですね。`ex: [1, 2, 3] == [1, 2, 3]`。リファレンスがコンプリートになるには、しばらく待つしかないと思います。